# Font/text size suddenly changed

Tags: fontsize, size

I'm currently writing my thesis using `\documentclass[12pt]{book}`, I've really liked the size of the text up until today. So I just finished adding my references, and suddenly the text of my document got smaller (see attached pictures). Does anyone know why this happened, and can I get it back to my original size?

So my preamble looks like this (I compile using xelatex)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%header footer sidnummer osv. 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markright {#1}{} }
\lhead[\emph{\textrm\leftmark}]{}
\chead[]{}
\rhead[]{\emph{\rightmark}}
\lfoot{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\rfoot{}
\usepackage{booktabs} %har med tabeller att göra
\usepackage{graphicx} %figurer
\usepackage{fontspec} %ändra font
\setromanfont{Georgia} %serif-font Gerogia
\setsansfont{Arial} %Sans seriffont Arial
\usepackage{sectsty} %har med font i rubriker/innehållsförteckning att göra
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily} %ändra font i innehållsförteckning till Arial
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}} %har att göra med numrering av sektioner
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{} %tar bort "chapter"
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{} %ngen numrering av kapitelnamn
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=bf]{caption} %utseende på figur/tabell text
\usepackage{chngcntr} %numrering av bilder/tabeller
\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}
\usepackage{gensymb} %grad-symbol
\renewcommand\bibname{References} %byter namn från bibliografi till referenser
\usepackage{float} %gör att man kan använda [H] efter begin figure för att placera figur precis där

\begin{document}
```

This is what my first page looked like before the text size changed
[image]

And this is what it looks like now
[image]

Edit:

tried compiling by just adding the first paragraph after the preamble

```
\begin{document}
first paragraph 
\end{document}
```

Then text size was the smaller size (as in the second picture).

So something has changed, without me adding anything in my preamble, causing the text to get smaller (as shown in the picture examples of my first page).

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Welcome, the only way to properly help you is by seeing a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) from you.

Comment: Looking at the text, i can see that the actual text is different. I bet this is not due to a bibliography item?

Comment: Write the first sentence of your introduction directly behind \begin{document} and add \end{document}. Then compile. Is the font size correct?

Comment: Have you checked the .log file, if there are any error messages?

Comment: @Johannes_B yes the text is different because I've edited it since the first example but that was what I had to illustrate the "normal" font size.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, good idea! No the font size is then also too small. I wonder why that is? I haven't changed the text (or at least this text has been this exact way and ended up with both font sizes). And I haven't changed anything in my preamble...

Comment: @samcarter I get a few error messages that I usually get like float is too wide etc. When I did what Ulrik suggested and still got too small text I got this message in the log file

Comment: Yes, i do understand. But in the time between the first screenshot, and the last, many things could have happened, that you are unaware of.

Comment: Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \perthousand.


Package gensymb Warning: Not defining \micro.

 .

Overfull \hbox (7.14258pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 33--34
\EU1/Georgia(0)/m/n/12 They help digest the food in our stomach (enzymes) and s
end signals through
[1] (./Avhandling_faktisk.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on Avhandling_faktisk.pdf (1 page).
SyncTeX written on Avhandling_faktisk.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on Avhandling_faktisk.log.

Comment: @Johannes_B Of course :) But this morning when I compiled it looked as it "should" and a few hours later it didn't. And all I didd in between was adding references...

Comment: Can you please add that extra information to the questiion? Edit button is in the left bottom. It will be much easier to read for us.

Comment: Maybe one of the references is broken and influences the whole project?

Comment: I unfortunately can't add the log file to my questions as I can only add two links. I don't get any error messages when doing BibTex but maybe... I'll have to do trial and error I guess...

Comment: The log fiile that is produced from the one paragraph example, you can directly copy the text in the question.

Comment: Add `\XeTeXtracingfonts= 1` to your preamble, and then compile with only one paragraph text. Delete first the old aux-file. Make sure that you are using the preamble above and not something else. If you still get the wrong font size, show the complete log-file.

Comment: If I test your code snipped (and adding missing `{` around `\end document`} I don't experience any problem with the font size. Have you tried to delete all auxiliary files and compile again?

Comment: you must have `\footnotesize` or `\small` or some such command somewhere if the font is already wrong by the start of the docuemnt, then it must be in an aux file or the preamble

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I now tested \XeTeXtracingfonts=1 with just the first paragraph after trashing the aux-file and still got too small font. I'll add the log to the question.I only have that command (footnote size) in my references and in one table and they haven't caused a problem before. It doesn't help if I delete the aux-file.

Comment: Your new edit talks about the font being too small rather than the font changing size. That is a very different question. Try commenting out your custom font configuration with the MWE with just one paragraph. Does the font look the correct size now? If so, it is just the design of the font. `12pt` Latin Modern Roman is not the same size as `12pt` Georgia unless by coincidence. Some fonts are just smaller than others.

Comment: @SaraK you are not showing the log-file, but only the terminal output. Find the file and show its content.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, oh sorry. I found the log file, is there an easier way for me to post it then copy paste?

Comment: I'm starting to think it may have something to do with the last update of TeXShop? I updated it the same day as my problem began and now if I open a new document, copy my preamble and just do the \begin{document} first paragraph \end{document} I end up with the same smaller size font...

Comment: Huh, how could that come about due to TeXShop? If you are sure, maybe try TeXStudio. :-)

Comment: @henry Maybe it's not a plausible explanation. I just don't understand how suddenly the text is smaller when I haven't changed anything in my preamble and all i could think about that had changed (besides me adding references and if that was the issue the problem wouldn't come up in my new document) was that I updated TeXShop...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42954/discussion-on-question-by-sarak-font-size-suddenly-changed) for better continuing the discussion.